# What algorithm to use to solve these equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given:

$x_1+x_2+x_3=S$

and

$x_1*x_2*x_3=P$

where all $0<x_i<M$
and all $x_i$ are integers.

What method/algorithm could be used to solve this system?

I thought of generating all integer partitions of S and consider the ones that satisfy $x_1*x_2*x_3=P$ to be part of the solution set. However, it is not practical to generalize this for large number of variables. I also considered plotting, but plotting won't work for large number of variables either.

I know that there may be multiple answers.

Comment: Depending on the values of $S,P$, it may be simpler to factorize $P$ and distribute the primes into the $x_i$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, sounds like a good idea - Thanks.